# SMTP sending email to wrong user

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

I have this web application (LAN) that sends an email when users registers to one of our events.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
        Dim message As New MailMessage()
        Dim Client As New SmtpClient("smtp.com", 25)

        message.From = New MailAddress("from@email.com")
        message.To.Add(New MailAddress(Email.SelectedValue)
        message.CC.Add(New MailAddress("cc@email.com"))

        message.Subject = "Here goes the subject"
        message.Body = "here goes the body"


        Client.Send(message)
```

The application sends the email without problems. The issue is that somehow a third person is enlisted in the cc, and receives a copy of the email!.  What could be the problem? The smtp? IIS?

Thanks

Comment: What does a debug view of `message` tell you? Are there any other addresses listed? otherwise, I'd say it's a setting on the mail server.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the .cc and .to recipients to you or others known to you and see what happens. I scratched my head over something like this a while back and the cc ended up being a distribution list!

Comment: ahh, I failed to consider distribution lists.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that there is no redirection or rule on your server that causes the mentioned behavior?

If you send a mail to two persons and the mail ends in three mailboxes the most common error is that one of the two original receivers of the mail has some redirection enabled.

Answer (score 0):

First try to use port 465. AND you need to add USER / PASSWORD in order to access any SMTP account.